# org-agenda clocktable to omit "0:00" entries

Tags: org-mode

Due to the large number of org-mode files I have, the default clocktable shown in agenda views has a many lines for files where there's no logged time, ie they show as `*0:00*`

How can I configure the clocktable to omit the table lines when no time is logged in that file?
eg, rather than

```
| File                                      | Headline                                     | Time   |      |
|-------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+--------+------|
|                                           | ALL *Total time*                             | *5:14* |      |
|-------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+--------+------|
| OrgTutorial.org                           | *File time*                                  | *0:00* |      |
|-------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+--------+------|
| bills.org                                 | *File time*                                  | *0:00* |      |
|-------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+--------+------|
| books.org                                 | *File time*                                  | *0:00* |      |
|-------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+--------+------|
| home.org                                  | *File time*                                  | *0:05* |      |
|-------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+--------+------|
 :
```

Only show

```
| File                                      | Headline                                     | Time   |      |
|-------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+--------+------|
|                                           | ALL *Total time*                             | *5:14* |      |
|-------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+--------+------|
| home.org                                  | *File time*                                  | *0:05* |      |
|-------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+--------+------|
  :
```

Comment: Stab in the dark:  if you specify `:compact` for the table, are the 0-entries elided?

Comment: Adding `:compact t` doesn't seem to make any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible with :fileskip0 t

More options are mentioned here: https://orgmode.org/manual/The-clock-table.html

Comment: Many thanks, yes it does.  have now set "org-agenda-clockreport-parameter-plist '(:link t :maxlevel 3 :fileskip0 t)" to get desired clocktable in the agendas